# Delete element of a vector using fstream C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I'm trying to delete an element from my vector which is storage in my file. I can add elements to my vector but I can't make it to delete an element. I tried to delete an element from vector without using fstream and it works perfectly, so my problem is the file. Is there any way to delete an element from my vector using fstream ?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void Menu()
{
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Add student" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Delete student" << endl;
    cout << "3 - All students" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
}

struct School
{
    string Name;
    string remove;
    int Ages;
    int Option;
};

int main()
{
    ofstream Myfile("practiceFile.txt", ios::app);

    School Students;
    vector <string> Names;

    if(!Myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        Menu();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Option: ";
        cin >> Students.Option;
        cin.ignore();

        if(Students.Option == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.Name);
            Names.push_back(Students.Name);

            for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
            {
                Myfile << Names[i] << endl;
            }
        }

        if(Students.Option == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.remove);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
            {
                if(Students.remove == Names[i])
                {
                    auto itr = find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), Students.remove);
                    if(itr != Names.end())
                    {
                        Names.erase(itr);
                    }
                }
            }     
        }
    }

    string line;
    ifstream NewFile("practiceFile.txt", ios::in);

    while(NewFile >> line)
    {
        if(Students.Option == 3)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }         
    } 
}
```

Comment: Delete it from the vector then write the entire file using the contents of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways you could go about this.

1. Rewrite the file whenever the list is updated, using the vector as a "guide" for what to write
   The caveat here is that if at any point your code throws an exception, the file will be left in an undefined state, potentially losing your data. Example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> Names;
std::ofstream MyFile("practiceFile.txt", std::ios::app);

// add or remove names

// clear the file using truncate mode
MyFile.close();
MyFile.open("practiceFile.txt", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
// write out the whole list of names
for (auto& Name : Names)
    MyFile << Name << std::endl;
```

2. Another (probably better) way would by writing to a temporary file, the only caveat here is if the temporary file exists, you'd be overwriting whatever exists in it

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> Names;
std::ofstream MyFile("practiceFile.txt", std::ios::app);

// add or remove names

// create a temp file
std::ofstream TempFile("practiceFile_temp.txt", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);

// write out the whole list of names
for (auto& Name : Names)
    TempFile << Name << std::endl;

// close all open files
TempFile.close();
MyFile.close();

// delete the old file
std::remove("practiceFile.txt");

// move the temp file to the new file
std::rename("practiceFile_temp.txt", "practiceFile.txt")
```

There's a handful of things you can do better here, like storing the filepath in some constant variable so you don't accidentally forget to change it somewhere or whatever, but no matter what you do you have to rewrite the file completely.

## Edit

As mentioned by Ted Lyngmo, a better approach for the second method would be to use `std::filesystem::rename`, which will automatically remove the old file and replace it with the new one. Also there's the added benefit of having C++ exceptions that you can propagate to callers if you ever get so far as to need that:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> Names;
std::ofstream MyFile("practiceFile.txt", std::ios::app);

// add or remove names

// create a temp file
std::ofstream TempFile("practiceFile_temp.txt", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);

// write out the whole list of names
for (auto& Name : Names)
    TempFile << Name << std::endl;

// close all open files
TempFile.close();
MyFile.close();

// move the temp file to the new file
std::filesystem::rename("practiceFile_temp.txt", "practiceFile.txt");
```

Comment: I wouldn't remove the old file though. Just let the renaming unlink it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename), "If new_filename exists, the behavior is implementation-defined."

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I'm gonna check that out now. @msimonelli

Comment: True. I would use [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) instead. Using thst ensures atomically removing the old file and renaming the new.

Comment: I've been struggling with #include <filesystem> . I can't make it work in my visual code. I've tried to update my visual code to C++17 but I can't. My configurations shows that I changed to C++17 but I still receive in my compilar: "The contents of <filesystem> are available only with C++17 or later". What can I do ? @msimonelli

Comment: You probably should search for duplicates first because the question of enabling c++11 or greater in Visual Studio code has been asked and answered dozens of times over the last few years. If you have a problem with your settings having tried the solution in the duplicate you should ask a new question showing that you have made the changes + your compiler version + errors + exact build commands.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what more to do. I've been following everypost here in StackOverflow and around internet, but nothing. I'm gonna make a new post about it. A bit stress and struggling with that all day. Thanks for you comment. @drescherjm